# Backbone View not updating on secondary fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone to display a list of items, being populated by a JSON on the server.

```
    //Models
    var Note = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var NoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Note,
            url:  "http://www.myserver.com/notes/notes.json"
    });

    var Notes = new NoteList;

    //Views
    var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "li",
            template: _.template($('#noteTemplate').html()),
            initialize: function() {
                    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
            },
            render: function() {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                    return this;
            }
            });

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#specificationNotes"),
            noteTemplate: _.template($('#noteTemplate').html()),
            initialize: function() {
                    this.listenTo(Notes, 'reset', this.addAll);
                    this.listenTo(Notes, 'all', this.render);
                    Notes.fetch({reset:true});
            },
            addOne: function(note) {
                    var view = new NoteView({model: note});
                    this.$("#notesList").append(view.render().el);
            },
            addAll: function() {
                    Notes.each(this.addOne, this);
            }
    });
    var App = new AppView;
```

The initial fetch grabs the content correct and displays the list.  I am using a jQuery dialog to "Add a Note" which simply POSTs to a RESTful API, after the ajax post is successful I call

```
    Notes.fetch();
```

and the Model is updated but the view does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AppView doesn't have a render method, so your 1st fetch causes a paint due to the handler bound to the 'reset' event, but the 2nd doesn't. Here's a brute force one:

```
render: function() {
   this.$el.html(""); // so we don't readd the same items on re-render
   this.addAll();
}
```

Inefficient, as it will repaint all the notes from scratch every time, but it should at least get you to see live changes on the screen. And maybe replace

```
this.listenTo(Notes, 'reset', this.addAll);
this.listenTo(Notes, 'all', this.render);
```

with

```
this.listenTo(Notes, 'reset', this.render);
this.listenTo(Notes, 'sync', this.render);
```